# Split string by space, but ignore space after some words and space in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help splitting a string in javascript by space, tab and comma, and ignoring space after "LLC" and "S-Corps" words and space inside quotes expression.

I have string:

```
const line = 'LLC "Company Name" S-Corps Company-1, LLC "Company-2" Company-3 S-Corps "Company-4"';
```

I need to get this:

```
["LLC "Company Name"", "S-Corps Company-1", "LLC "Company-2"", "Company-3", "S-Corps "Company-4""]
```

this is my code:

```
const words = line.split(/(?<!LLC|S-Corps)[\s,]/);
```

and I get this:

```
["LLC "Company", "Name"", "S-Corps Company-1", "", "LLC "Company-2"", "Company-3", "S-Corps "Company-4""]
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to assert not `LLC` or `S-Corps` to the left, and assert pairs of double quotes to the right.

To prevent empty entries after the split, you can repeat the character class `[\s,]+` 1 or more times.

```
(?<!LLC|S-Corps)[\s,]+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!LLC|S-Corps)` Negative lookbehind, assert not LLC or S-Corps directly to the left
- `[\s,]+` Match 1+ occurrences of a whitespace char or `,`
- `(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` Positive lookahead to assert pairs of `"` till the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/06ibKU/1)

```js
const line = 'LLC "Company Name" S-Corps Company-1, LLC "Company-2" Company-3 S-Corps "Company-4"';
const regex = /(?<!LLC|S-Corps)[\s,]+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g;
console.log(line.split(regex));
```